# How to create Transparent Activity in Android for Smartglasses

Tags: android, background, transparent, augmented-reality, epson

Working with the Epson BT-200 smart-glasses, I stumbled upon a problem and can't seem to solve it. I would like to start off with a 3d Object centered in the middle of the screen with a transparent background. (basically looking through the lenses at the real world, you see a 3d object) I have managed to set the background transparent by doing the following:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
...
```

Even though the background is now transparent and the 3d Object is centered in the middle, I still see the "android desktop"! I would be more than happy for help or tips on how to get rid of the "desktop"!

Comment: you can run your primary camera as your background and add a transluent gradient on it like #22000000.

Comment: Do you really need a camera in the typical sense like a phone or tablet because you are basically looking at the real world through the lenses?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this ?~